# How do I convert 6V DC to 12V DC in a relatively small form factor.

Tags: microcontroller, led, switch-mode-power-supply

I want to convert 6V DC from batteries to 12 V DC to drive 1m of LED strip (60 LEDs per meter) whilst using the 6 V to power
a microcontroller
4 TPIC5C569 Shift Register
1 SD Card
32 LEDs
Also, the application is worn on your body, so weight is an issue, and the reason why I want to use 4AAA batteries instead of 8 (Board space is another).

So essentially I'm looking for a circuit that is lighter and smaller than a 4 AAA battery pack, is mostly SMD, which can drive up to 1200mA of current.

On the other hand, if you do know some other way (non boost conversion) that will yield the required voltages (6,12,3.3) and currents (~200mA,1200mA,600mA), it'd help me greatly if you could also list it.

Comment: As Miceuz's answer points out, your power demand is way too much for your batteries. Your LED strip is your main load so you'll need to figure out how to reduce that. If you tell us more about what you're doing with this, we may be able to help you solve your real problem. So ... What LED strip are you proposing to use (datasheet link would be best)? What kind of lighting does the LED strip need to be seen in? Is it single-color or multicolor? How often do you need to change the colors? How long do you need the batteries to last?

Answer (score 2):

A boost converter is what you're looking for. The amperage will be the most important factor determining the size. For approx. 1A you can expect the circuit to be quite small, too. There are literally hundreds of different ICs that would probably do the job.

You can build the boost converter using your own parts and design a pcb, or buy a small module that's ready to run out of the box. [This random one I found after typing "step up regulator" might fit your size requirements](http://www.ebay.com/itm/LM2577-DC-DC-Converter-3-34V-to-4-35V-15W-Step-up-Power-Supply-Boost-Module-/160879273630), although I recommend designing a board yourself. Datasheets for the many switching regulators include example pcb designs made according to all of the design rules.

As for the rest of your project - assuming you want to draw out 1200mA from the 12V output, that means more than 2.5A from the AAA batteries! I'm not so sure they can handle that. Batteries of different manufacturers, age, and under different physical conditions such as temperature will vary in the maximum current they can supply. Perhaps lithium batteries can fare better.

Comment: Oh, and as miceuz pointed out, your batteries will drain so fast you won't notice.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to rethink your design as 4AAA batteries will not last for long at these currents. Roughly, one AAA battery contains 1.41 Watt-hours, four of them would contain 5.54 Wh.

Your design needs 6V*0.2A + 12V*1.2A * 3.3V*0.6A = 17.58 Watts

And some more energy would be lost in conversion from 6V to 12V and 3.3V.

BTW, my guess is 6V might be a bit too much for microcontroller to function reliably. For example, Attiny44 has 6V specified as absolute maximum - you don't want to run parts in such conditions.

Comment: What's "Watt/hours"?

Comment: http://www.allaboutbatteries.com/Energy-tables.html lists capacity of AAA's in watt-hours. Ampere-hours * voltage.

Comment: Aha! watt-hours, indeed. But in your answer you write watt/hour, twice, and that doesn't mean anything.

Comment: I think your math is off. I get 6*0.2 + 12 * 1.2 + 3.3 * 0.6 = 17.6 W. Still way too much for 4 AAA batteries, but only about half what you calculated.